# Не могу подключить базу данных MySQl WorkBench к боту телеграмм на python

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot

Создал базу данных и мне нужно чтобы бот сохранял в неё информацию и сверял с уже существующей, но когда пытаюсь подключить выдаёт кучу ошибок и я никак не могу понять в чём проблема.

```
from aiogram.types import chat
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import connect, Error
from telebot import types
from telebot import callback_data
from DataBase_Connect import con



parus = telebot.TeleBot("Token")

flag = 0

m: {chat}
@parus.message_handler(commands=["Начать"])
def start(m, res=False):
    parus.send_message(m.chat.id, "Привет")
    parus.send_message(m.chat.id, "Для того чтобы войти в группу вы должны зарегистрироваться")
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Регистрация", callback_data="reg")
    keyboard.add(callback_button)
    parus.send_message(m.chat.id, "Для регистрации нажмите на кнопку", reply_markup=keyboard)


@parus.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "reg":
            parus.send_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, text="Введите ФИО")

@parus.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def reg(message):
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into Villager (id, fio, phone_number, entrance, flat) values (1, " + message.text + ", '1', '1', '1');")
    cur.fetchall()

parus.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

вот код подключения

````
try:
    with connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="1234",
        database="Parus"
    ) as con:
        print("Con")
except Error as e:
    print(e)```


и ошибки 
C:\Users\anime\Desktop\PyProjects\Project1\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\anime\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py 
Con
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anime\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 37, in <module>
    parus.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "C:\Users\anime\Desktop\PyProjects\Project1\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1043, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\anime\Desktop\PyProjects\Project1\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1118, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\anime\Desktop\PyProjects\Project1\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1074, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\anime\Desktop\PyProjects\Project1\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 147, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\anime\Desktop\PyProjects\Project1\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 90, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anime\Desktop\PyProjects\Project1\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 6770, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "C:\Users\anime\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 34, in reg
    con.cursor().execute("insert into Villager (id, fio, phone_number, entrance, flat) values (1, " + message.text + ", '1', '1', '1');")
  File "C:\Users\anime\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 678, in cursor
    raise OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.

Process finished with exit code 1
````

Comment: Убедитесь, что вы указали верные данные для подключения (хост, порт, логин, пароль, бд)